# WordPress not working on Varnish + Nginx based Ubuntu VPS

Tags: nginx, vps, wordpress, varnish

I set up a Ubuntu based Linode VPS with Nginx and Varnish on it. However i am not able to access anything on the IP or site address.

IP: 176.58.98.79
Site: http://www.articledexter.info

When i try to access either of them i get this error

Error 503 Service Unavailable

Service Unavailable

Guru Meditation:

XID: 1357161149

Varnish cache server

Which configuration files need to modified to increase the timeout issues ?
Experts need your help !

Comment: What's in your logs?

Comment: Why do you think it's a timeout issue?

Comment: @LucasKauffman : The Varnish Log or server related logs ?

Comment: @womble: In general 503 errors are related to time out stuff right ?

Comment: All of your logs until you find something useful.

Comment: @SameerManas: No, it means that the service is unavailable.  A 504 "Gateway Timeout" is related to "time out stuff" much more directly.

Comment: But the Nginx is installed and the service is producing bind errors when i start the nginx service. In the Nginx.conf i have specified Nginx to listen at port 80.
I don't understand how to make Nginx and Varnish exist with each other

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, you didn't give any attention to the documentation. Read it. Specifically [this page](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/backend_servers.html).

Varnish should run on port 80 (default http port) and nginx on a different one, for example 8080.

```
backend default {
      .host = "127.0.0.1";
      .port = "8080";
}
```

The reason why you're getting 503 error is because there's no backend running (or even set up).

Comment: I have indeed setup Varnish on 80 and Nginx configuration on 8080. The reason is that Nginx is not starting on port 8080 but trying to start in port 80. This is producing bind errors.

Comment: Check if you have the default configuration file there, or the example part of the configuration. Check both nginx.conf and sites-enabled folder.